# trying to make a function execution function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to make a function that does this `callFunction();`

I'm trying to execute a JS function from a PHP file using AJAX

Because I have AJAX `responseText` I tried using

`<script type="text/javascript"> callFunction(); </script>`

but it didn't work, Im trying to do something like this

```
function exec(func , arg) {
  func(arg); // executes the function
}
```

if something like that doesn't exist, How can I call a function with AJAX from a PHP request(Via the GET method)

The error I get when I try it is

> func is not a function

JS AJAX code

```
                var emailVal = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var passVal = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var uVal = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var busVar = document.getElementById("businessname").value;
                var firstVal = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
                var params = "email=" + emailVal + "&password=" + passVal + "&businessname="+busVar + "&username="+uVal+"&firstname="+firstVal;
                var url = "business.php";
                http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http.open("POST", url, true);

                //Send the proper header information along with the request
                http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                http.onreadystatechange = function() {  //Call a function when the state changes.
                    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        console.log(http.responseText);
                        exececc(http.responseText , null);
                    }
                }

                http.send(params);
```

PHP code

`echo '<script type="text/javascript"> callFunction(); </script>';`

Comment: you need to specify the question more. Share with us more code, etc. it's hard to tell what are you trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Sure! I'm currently adding the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I see the problem, you are passing a string to the executeFunction()

In that case try this, ensure that the values you are assigning to the variables fnName & params are strings and no JSON objects. for example you might need to do  data["fnName"] to extract the function name from your data JSON object. You can always test this by dumping them to the console to check the data type.

```js
function say($something) {
  console.log($something);
  return;
}

var fnName = "say";
var params = "Hello world"

window[fnName](params);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you pass a valid function name to the function that executes it, like this:

```js
function saySomething($something){
 console.log($something);
}

function executeFunction(func,arg){
 func(arg);
}


executeFunction(saySomething,"Yay, it works!");
```

Comment: `func is not a function`

Comment: This must be that you are either passing it the wrong name, in the above its saySomething as the first arg when calling executeFunction. Or the file where you are declaring the function is not being included before you make this call

Comment: here's what I did:

Comment: `console.log(http.responseText); // got the right value executeFunction(http.responseText);`

Comment: I removed the arg argument btw

Comment: what is http.responseText? I imagine its a JSON object?

Comment: It's the AJAX response, which is in this case 'emailDoesnt'

Comment: without the single quotes

Comment: Ok I added another answer, give it a try.

Comment: nvm, I'm just gonna use if commands. no need for that mess I don't have a lot of functions I want so it's fine :/! Thanks brad!